# Auto attach unsubscribe to mailgun members lists

Tags: mailgun

I am using mailgun to setup several members mail lists (each member can send a message that is received by other members of the group). I would like to have an unsubscribe footer added to these messages so that members always have a way to unsubscribe.

The default behavior is that each message just contains the message sent, no unsubcribe link is added. The domain unsubscribe tracking only adds the link to read-only lists not member lists.

Has anyone done this or have a good idea of how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach footer mentioned below and include variable `%mailing_list_unsubscribe_url%`

`<div align="center">If you wish to unsubscribe from our newsletter, click <a href="%mailing_list_unsubscribe_url%">here</a></div>'`